# Tkinter Entry widget color fading

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In my new application I want when the mouse is over the entry() widget to change color (this I know how to do it) but I want the color to change gradually, not immediately.

This is my code:

```
# User_Line Focus In/Out
    def User_Line_Focus_In(self, event):
        self.User_Line.configure(bg = "#DCDCDC")

    def User_Line_Focus_Out(self, event):
        self.User_Line.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a method which increments the colour and you need to use tkinter's [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) which registers an alarm callback that is called after a given time. You then need to reference it recursively in order to get the fading effect you want.

```
    def incrementHex(hex_str, increment): #with hex_str in format "#FFFFFF" or any colour
        red = int(hex_str[1:3],16) #specifies base for integer conversion
        green = int(hex_str[3:5],16)
        blue = int(hex_str[5:],16)
        red += increment #increment can be negative
        green += increment
        blue += increment
        new_hex_str = "#" + str(hex(red)) + str(hex(blue)) + str(hex(green))
        return new_hex_str

    def Fade(self, start_hex, increment):
        new_hex = self.incrementHex(start_hex, increment)
        self.User_Line.configure(bg = new_hex)
        #where self.master is the parent widget as defined in the __init__ method...
        self.master.after(50,lambda: self.Fade(new_hex, increment)) #or any time interval in milliseconds
        #you'll probably need some code to stop it fading here, but I'll let you tackle that one :)

    def User_Line_Focus_In(self, event):
        self.Fade("#FFFFFF",-1) #could be any colour and increment
```

I haven't been able to test it, but I think it should work in principle. An extension of this would be to have different increments for red, green and blue.

Comment: How I do the same conversion in RGB scale?

Comment: @KotropoulosLeontios If you mean do each red, green and blue separately, change the incrementHex function only deal with one colour at a time, take the string slicing outside of the incrementHex function and put it in the Fade function. Have three increment values being parsed to Fade so that each colour can be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to pull up your socks on this one and do some coding (tkinter doesn't have this built in)

So what you are looking for is :

- An algorithm to go from color one to color two and get intermediate colors. (Hex values are just numbers in base 16 but they can be added or subtracted like normal numbers)

The simplest solution would be to just run the algorithm (color_difference here)

```
def fade_colors(event, new_color):
    old_color = event.widget.cget('bg')       
    for color in color_difference(old_color, new_color):
        event.widget.configure(color)
        time.sleep(0.1)

widget.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: fade_colors(event, color))
```

- You might also like to cancel the operation if the user leaves the widget. Take a look at the [built in sched module.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sched.html)

If you find your gui becomes unresponsive during the fading you could consider using the after method, you can read [this excellent blog](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.de/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html) post on non blocking gui techniques in python and tkinter. This may not be an issue if you cancel the callback as soon as the user leaves the widget (thus freeing up tkinter to handle his other actions)

Comment: You must **never** use `time.sleep` when Tkinter is in `mainloop` as this stops the mainloop running, meaning that interactivity with the window stops. Tkinter has an `after` method to replace this which I have used in my answer.